# ARCGIS : AGSGraphic does not return object in attribute dictionary

Tags: ios, arcgis

```
AGSGraphic *graphic;
AGSPoint *graphicPoint;
NSMutableDictionary *graphicAttributes;
AGSPictureMarkerSymbol *graphicSymbol;


   //Graphic for demonstrating custom callout with buttons
    graphicPoint = [AGSPoint pointWithX:sample.latitude y:sample.longitude spatialReference:self.mapView.spatialReference];

    graphicAttributes=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
    [graphicAttributes setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sample.sampleId] forKey:@"SampleID"];
    [graphicAttributes setObject:mapData.SurveyData forKey:@"SurveyData" ];

    NSLog(@"%@",[graphicAttributes objectForKey:@"SurveyData"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [graphicAttributes allKeys]);

    graphicSymbol = [AGSPictureMarkerSymbol pictureMarkerSymbolWithImageNamed:@"MapPin_Blue.png"];
    graphic = [AGSGraphic graphicWithGeometry:graphicPoint symbol:graphicSymbol attributes:graphicAttributes infoTemplateDelegate:self];

    NSLog(@"%@", [[graphic allAttributes] allKeys]);

    [self.graphicsLayer addGraphic:graphic];
```

The Log gives keys Allkeys as `SampleID` alone, not getting the `SurveyData`,Which is an `NSArray`!
Why is it so?

Comment: No comments until now

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and the log showed both keys.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the AGSGraphic's attributes only support NSNull, NSString, NSDate, and NSNumber from ArcGIS 10.1.1.you can refer to the documents.

My Solution is to build my own AGSGraphic by extends AGSGraphic with any attributes you need. something like below:

```
@interface CustomAGSGraphic : AGSGraphic

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *attrDictionary;

@end
```

it works like a charm. hope it could help.